# ui router $location.path() not work as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AnguLarJs , i'm using ui router ,i have a question if i have :

```
$state.go('customer.customerDetail', {
        selectedCustomer: customer
    });
```

which plan is an object how can i do it with $location.path() .
 i tried

```
 $location.path('/customer/customerdetail').search({ selectedCustomer : customer });
```

but it did not work.
this is my config

```
.state('customer.customerDetail', {
    url: '/customerdetail',
    templateUrl: 'views/customerDetail.html',
    controller: 'customerDetailCtrl',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Customer detail'
    },
    params: {
        selectedCustomer: null,

    },
    resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired,
        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    files: ['js/plugins/hammer/hammer.min.js']
                },
                {
                    files: ['css/customerDetail.css'],
                    cache: false,
                },
            ]);
        }
    }
})
```

what i'm doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: why not use `state.go`

Comment: when you use `location` with `search`, it will print the parameters u passed in the url.  If `customer` object has multiple properties url might get messed up. it's ideal to use the first option